# Cross-Browser Transparent Letters

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I am creating a blog, and on the top of the blog is an image of some scene (I used a picture of NYC) with the text of the most recent blog post over top of it. I thought it would be really cool to have the letters have an outline, but can still be transparent so the viewer can still see the image.

I tried text-shadow with a transparent color, but all I got was a black letter (which I didn't expect but makes sense). I ended up using the webkit-text-stroke property, which isn't cross browser at all. I've attached an image of it in both Chrome and Firefox, with a text shadow behind it so you can see how a text shadow appears (kind of) without a color present.

Is there a way to have the desired effect (a border around the text, but no color) in modern browsers? For IE9 and down I'll just use a solid black color so.

This is the code I'm using to get the below effect:

```
figcaption { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    left: 20px; 
    font-size: 90px; 
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #1F1F1F; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);}
```

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts.

This example isn't exactly what you have described, but the result is good and should work well cross-browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/JHvgp/

The key CSS is

```
h1.figcaption { 
color:white;
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0px; 
left: 20px; 
font-size: 90px; 
opacity: 0.35;
filter: alpha(opacity=35);
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
}
```

Alternatively, maybe it's possible to do something with with [sIFR](http://www.google.ca/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=sifr&oq=sifr) ... not sure about this though.

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Good suggestion from [Adrien Be](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759452/adrien-be) below -- with improved cross-browser transparency code:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I can work with this. Thanks David!

Comment: This is the way to go, however I'd use CSSTRICKS "really" cross-browser opacity properties http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Thanks @AdrienBe , that code looks better to me as well. Added a link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

[I have no real ready-to-use solution here; but my thoughts on this are getting too long for a comment, so excuse me for putting this here.]

---

Cross-browser that’s kinda hard to achieve. I’ve looked into ways to get this kind of effect as well (and wasn’t satisfied with having it work webkit-only), and I came up with stuff like using dynamically created Canvas or SVG images that I draw the text on and then manipulating alpha values (canvas) or applying mask/filter effects (SVG).

But it’s a bit of a challenge to get the font rendering/positioning exactly right, and when text has to flow over multiple lines it gets even more complex. Best way I found for that is to split up the text into multiple `span` elements, one for each word; and then I place a Canvas or SVG image containing just that word as a background image for the span element. Big advantage here: The browser still takes care of text flow, like where to break text into a new line etc., because that’s a bit of a hassle to implement yourself in Canvas or SVG. And text flow also automatically adapts if the area the text gets displayed in changes size (f.e. user resizing browser window). What needs a little extra care is handling text resizing after the effect is applied – when user changes font size in their browser, the text I painted on my image might not fit any more – although using SVG and relative units that can be handled quite automatically as well. The other workarounds are either using `background-size` to scale the background image to the size of the span containing the word, or somehow capture that resize-“event” and re-draw images dynamically.

Using background images has the advantage that I can still keep the original HTML text in place – just setting it to `transparent`, so that when the user f.e. starts selecting text on the page it will still show up as actual text and is copy&paste-able.

---

But for a small effect like this it’s quite a lot of work … so I decided in the end to give up on that, and postponed using “transparent letters” until browser support for easier solutions like the webkit one you mentioned gets wider.